# How is this source actually connected in the circuit?

Tags: voltage, batteries, source, vcc

[image]

I have seen this way of connecting the source in a couple of books now but I still am not sure if I am getting it right.

[image]

This is how I am interpreting it, I have a feeling I'm very much wrong.
The original picture is taken from The Art of Electronics. Thank you!

Comment: You have it right... what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: You are right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it right... Not sure what makes you think otherwise?

Whenever you see a voltage name like the +10V on a schematic, you know it is connected to some power rail or connector where the power is inserted into the circuit. All places marked with the same name are connected to the same place.

The same thing goes for the ground symbols. It is simply a shortcut to remove clutter from the schematic instead of showing "wires" for every connection.

In this example you are using a simple battery, so the +10V connects to the positive side of the battery and the ground to the negative side.

If the power is supplied from some other source the rail may be connected through regulators and filters to the originating power source.